# Question about proof of conditional distribution of normal distribution is normal (Hogg book)

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

[image]

I'm trying to understand the proof of this theorem in the "Introduction to mathematical statistics" by Hogg, McKean and Craig. I can understand most of the part but I couldn't fully understand the last part.

I know that W and $X_2$ are independent so we derived the conditional distribution of W given $X_2$. But why do we have to use the independence condition in the sentence that I highlighted?

My thought is to use [the sum of independent normal distribution is normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables). Am I right? If not, why is that for?

Comment: I have little idea what these symbols mean. Further, it is not a good way to reason about conditional distributions regarding gaussian vectors. In any case, if $W$ and $X_2$ are independent, then $W+f(X_2)$ conditional on $X_2 = x$ is distributed as $W+f(x)$

Comment: If $W$ and $X_2$ are not independent, then you would need to compute $W$ conditional on $X_2 = x$. Say it's $W_x$. Then $W+f(X_2)$ conditional on $X_2=x$ is distributed as $W_x+f(x)$

Comment: @Andrew What did you mean is following?: Since $W$ and $X_2$ are independent, $W$ follows $N_{m}(sth above)$, $W$ given $X_2=x_2$ is always follows that normal distribution whatever $x_2$ is. So, $X_1$ given that $X_2=x_2$ follows $N_{m}(sth above)+$f(x_2)$ and therefore its distribution is normal since normal+constant?

Comment: Yes that’s correct

Comment: @Andrew Thanks so much!